# Python - Small string concatenation/syntax error with bubblesort module

Tags: python, string, variables, concatenation

I am developing a program which bubble sorts a series of numbers entered by the user. I seem to be having a small syntax error. This is what I have:

```
my_list = '[' + input('Please enter 5 numbers, separated by commas. ') + ']'
length = len(my_list)
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length-1):
        if my_list[j] > my_list[j+1]:
            my_list[j], my_list[j+1] = my_list[j+1], my_list[j]
        print(my_list)
```

This returns me with:

```
File "C:/Users/Luke/Dropbox/Programming/SDD real.py", line 19, in <module>
my_list[j], my_list[j+1] = my_list[j+1], my_list[j]
```

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

If I set my_list to a predefined number list, such as: [1,5,2,3,4], the bubblesort functions as intended. I just need to figure out how to correctly store the numbers entered by the user in an array.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
my_list = '[' + input('Please enter 5 numbers, separated by commas. ') + ']'
```

With:

```
my_list = list(map(int, input('Please enter 5 numbers, separated by commas. ').strip().split(',')))
```

Or:

```
my_list = [int(i) for i in input('Please enter 5 numbers, separated by commas. ').strip().split(',')]
```

In your code, `my_list` isn't a list, it's a string. Use the `str.strip` method to remove whitespace and the `str.split` method to split a string and return the resulting list.

Comment: You also need to convert the number strings to integers after splitting.

Comment: @icktoofay OP is clearly using Python 3, otherwise they would get an error on line 1 after inputting (what would be evaluated as) a tuple of integers.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you should create a list. Instead, do this:

```
>>> my_list = list(input('Please enter 5 numbers, separated by commas. '))
Please enter 5 numbers, separated by commas. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>>> print my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This only works in Python 2 though, and I'm assuming the OP is using Python 3 because of the `print` function.

Comment: My mistake, was unsure if this was python 3 or not

Comment: This works, thank you! I am still having an issue though. That returns me with a sort which includes the commas, such as: Please enter a series of numbers, preferably around 10. (i.e: 5172610924). 1,2
[',', '1', '2']
[',', '1', '2']
[',', '1', '2']
[',', '1', '2']
[',', '1', '2']
[',', '1', '2']